# Delay timer after first fire

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a timer in my application that triggers a certain event:

```
myTimer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self,
    selector: "searchForDrivers:", userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
```

The first time the timer is triggered, it has a delay of 10 ms. I don’t want the delay on the first timer trigger, but I'd like the second trigger to be delayed by 10 ms. How can I achieve this?

Comment: just call your method `searchForDrivers:` then after its completed call the timer version?

Comment: i.e i have to implement timer inside searchForDrivers method??

Comment: if that is the best way for your purpose, otherwise just call the method before you make the timer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First schedule the timer as you've done.

```
timer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    10.0, target: self,
    selector: "searchForDrivers:",
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats: true
)
```

Then, immediately afterwards, fire `timer`.

```
timer.fire()
```

According to the documentation,

> You can use this method to fire a repeating timer without interrupting its regular firing schedule. If the timer is non-repeating, it is automatically invalidated after firing, even if its scheduled fire date has not arrived.

See the [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do that is you can use two timers for that like:

```
var myTimer = NSTimer()
var secondTimer = NSTimer()
```

After that you can set two timers this way:

```
myTimer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0, target: self,
    selector: "searchForTRuckDrivers", userInfo:nil, repeats: false)
secondTimer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self,
    selector: "searchForTRuckDrivers", userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
```

You can set first timer with delay 0 which will not repeat again while set another timer with delay 10 and it will repeat again and again.

After that in method you can invalidate first timer this way:

```
func searchForTRuckDrivers() {        
    if myTimer.valid {
        myTimer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

This will remove first timer but second timer will call this method with delay.

Hope it will help.